# What is the safe way to add library-overridable custom properties?

Tags: python, properties

I've had this EnumProperty for a while:

```py
class Foo_Bars(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    frindles = [
        ("0", "Foo", "Foo"),
        ("1", "Bar", "Bar"),
        ("2", "Baz", "Baz"),
        ("3", "Quux", "Quux"),
    ]
    frindle_level: EnumProperty(
        name="Frindle Level",
        description="The level of the Frindle.",
        default="1",
        items=frindles
    )
```

Works great, can even keyframe it.

Now I'd like to override this property in a .blend file that links to this one. I can see there are a handful of `option`s that seem to be related:

- `HIDDEN`
- `SKIP_SAVE`
- `ANIMATABLE`
- `ENUM_FLAG`
- `LIBRARY_EDITABLE`

And an `override` field that supports the args `LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE` and `USE_INSERTION`. But I can't seem to find any documentation on them, so I'm not sure what combinations of these properties I should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the parameter `override={"LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE"}` when defining the prop.

So you'll have :

```
frindle_level: EnumProperty(
    name="Frindle Level",
    description="The level of the Frindle.",
    default="1",
    items=frindles,
    override={"LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE"},
)
```

[Source](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty)